# structure problem in Relational DBMS creation

Tags: c, sql

For learning and understanding purpose, I currently want to try to make a small relational `DBMS` with simple features like (for now) only sequential reading/writing and **CREATE TABLE**, **INSERT**, **SELECT**, **UPDATE** and **DELETE** management.

I am currently on the "*think*" part of the project and I am stuck on the way to store the read data in memory. First I was thinking of putting them properly on a structure, but the problem is that tables are all different, know the type of each column is not an issue, but I am not sure C provide a way to make fully dynamic structure.

My second and current idea is to make a simple `char array` of the required length and just get the data by order with cast. But I am not sure if it is the good way to do that part, so I wanted to ask for your opinion and advices about that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

nb: I hope my question is enough clear and understandable, I still lack of pratice in english

Comment: Your question indicates that even a "little" DBMS may be a too heavy goal for the first steps in C. And yes, C of course provides means to build dynamic structures of all kind.

Comment: @JensG As I was think, I have miss something in my message. It's not my first step in C at all and I know it well, and as dynamic structures I was more speaking of the content of the struct (if my table have two int and a text column I will have struct myTable { int a, int b, char *c; =; inside, if it's one int and a real, i will have struct myTable { int a; float b; };, I was thinking of "dynamic" in that sens.

Comment: Ok, then just a few thoughs: A table consists basically of a list of field (column) descriptors. Each of them has (at least) a data type assigned, and a pointer to some other memory, where the actual data are stored. These exact layout of These data depend on the data type set in the column descriptor. With C++, the columns descriptors could inherit from a base class, and the columns could be Held in a list<column> or the like. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time since I programmed in straight C, but I think I can point you in the right direction.  There are 2 things you can use together.  First somthing like:

```
union data {
    // all the data types you will support
}
```

You will need a way to identify each element.  That is where struct can come in:

```
struct dataNode {
   data *value;
   // some type id system with either enum or ints
}
```

A row of data then becomes a linked list & a result set a linked list of linked lists.  You will probably need to straighten out the syntax, but it is a start.

Comment: Oh, good idea ! I always forget union exist, that will certainly help me.